# Gradle sync failed: invalid type code: 00

Tags: java, android, html, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

I am getting the error

> Gradle sync failed: invalid type code: 00

using version Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3

through my research I found a fix that works but is outdated, before you could go to settings, languages and frameworks, android experimental and then unchecked `only sync the active variant` but this option is no longer available in this newer version of android studio...

does anyone know a work around or where this option is now located?

[image]